# Check if external API is online / offline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to have your thoughts about how I can check if an external API is available or not.

In my controllers, I'm calling some API's and I don't want to call them if they are not available otherwise it will thrown an error in my app.

I think I have to make a job running each X seconds and check if the API is available or not. If she's not, I have a variable that I'm setting to false for example.

Is it the best way for you?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

I had to do a similar thing recently with testing whether some of our partner sites had gone live yet.  I did it like this

```
#replace this with the access point url of the api
url = "http://www.google.com"
status = `curl -sL -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n" "#{url}" -o /dev/null`.to_i
```

this will return the response status code, which will be 200 if the api is up and running, or 404 (or some other error) if it's not.

Comment: But, as Kristjan says it's better to assume that they will fail sometimes and have a rescue in place to deal with it in an orderly fashion.

Answer (score 2):

The way you describe will work much of the time, but there's still a window between when the API goes down and when your job runs that your controller may try to hit the API. The safer way, and with fewer moving parts, is to catch the network exception (`ETIMEDOUT`, etc.) in your controller.

Comment: I agree with this plus I'd wrap it in a while. Which is to say, when you make the call, while API is down, ping 3 or so times, if it works, execute, if not, throw the exception.

Comment: In a script using a flaky API, I'd agree that trying a few times could be more robust. In a controller, I worry about the remote API taking 10 seconds to time out. Try that 3 times, and now your controller hasn't responded for 30 - any user is long gone, and you might end up DoSing yourself while all your server threads/dynos/etc. sit there waiting. Generally, it's safest and best for the end client if you bubble the error through.

Comment: Haha. Actually. I assumed he was calling the API in a background job.